# how to access an Oracle procedure's OUT parameter when calling it?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

If I write a simple function `doSomething`, I can get its result by executing :

```
select doSomething() from dual;
```

But, if I wish to call a procedure that has an `OUT` cursor being passed to it (along with another int parameter), how do I call that procedure inside a query and access the result of the cursor ?

Calling it inside a query is not compulsory.. its just that I want to access the results of that procedure

Comment: You want to execute the procedure to see what is the result? What does your procedure returns? Some kind of ref_cursor?

Comment: @Polppan it returns a custom cursor with multiple columns (all varchar type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a procedure like

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE your_procedure(out_cursor OUT sys_refcursor)
    IS
    BEGIN
        OPEN out_cursor FOR
            SELECT  employee_name
              FROM  employees;

    END;
    /
```

Once you create your procedure wrap the procedure in a function which returns a cursor like the following

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION your_function
    RETURN sys_refcursor
AS
    o_param  sys_refcursor;
BEGIN
    o_param := NULL;
    your_procedure(o_param);
    RETURN o_param;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
    THEN
        -- raise                                  

    WHEN OTHERS
    THEN
        -- raise
END your_function;
/
```

To see the results from sql do as

```
select your_function from dual;
```

Update 1

To see result in SQL Developer

Step 1

Double click on your results in SQL Developer

[Results][1]

Step 2 Single Click on the button with dots. That will pop up the values

[Grid][2]

Comment: Thanks.. but it prints out data (incomplete) in a single row.. like "{<FIRST_NAME=Ellen,LAST_NAME=Abel>,<FIRST_NAME=Sundar,LAST_NAME=Ande>,<FIRST_NAME=Mozhe,"

Comment: If you edit your question and post your your code that would help in debugging more. When I executed in sql plus it executes row by row.

Comment: I just copy pasted you exact code...though I am selecting first_name, last_name from the employees table.. I am using SqlDeveloper..

Comment: I executed in sqlplus and TOAD, results showed in rows with emp_number and emp_name.  Try in sqlplus how it works.

Comment: @Daud When you execute in SQLDeveloper double click or single click on results grid with button with `three dots ...` It will pop up a screen where you could see the results in a data grid.

Comment: I am sorry, but I can't find the button with 3 dots.. the number of rows being returned is also 1. The oracle server is on another machine and I can't ssh into that..

Comment: @Daud I have updated my answer. I have mentioned how you could view the results in SQL Developer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that.. but this is different from my view of SqlDeveloper (3.0.04). Please see http://tinypic.com/r/kd0i1y/6

Comment: @Daud let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19429/discussion-between-polppan-and-daud)

Answer (score 0):

You can Do Something Like This

```
select doSomething(cursor (select int_col from your_table)) colname from dual
```

Hope this Help

Comment: the OUT variable has to be populated inside the procedure.. and I wish to access all the fields of the cursor.. shouldn't we be passing an empty cursor ?