# How to select value of variable in ORACLE

Tags: sql-server, oracle, declare

Below is the SQL Server's syntax to select variable as a record

```
DECLARE @number AS INTEGER;
SET @number = 10;
SELECT @number;
```

How can I do this in ORACLE?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Sagar Nannaware

Answer (score 1):

Edited based on comment:
One way you can access the variable value assigned by a procedure is through a function again.
Example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE your_procedure(out_number OUT number)
    IS
    BEGIN
      out_number:=1;
    END;
```

function to retrieve the procedure's output

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION your_function
    RETURN number
AS
    o_param  number;
BEGIN
    o_param := NULL;
    your_procedure(o_param);
    RETURN o_param;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
    THEN
       return 0; --basically how you want to handle your errors.

END your_function;
```

Now you can select the output of the procedure

```
select your_function from dual;
```

Useful link [how to access an Oracle procedure's OUT parameter when calling it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13339899/how-to-access-an-oracle-procedures-out-parameter-when-calling-it)

---

If you are trying to create a variable to access anywhere in your application in oracle.
You can do it by creating function and calling it from dual.

```
SQL>create or replace function foo return number
  as
   x number;
   begin
   x:=1;
   return 1;
   end;

Function created.

SQL>select foo from dual;

     FOO
----------
         1
```

Please check following link for more details
[example link] (http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1562813956388)

Comment: First of all, thank you for your reply. I can not use the user defined function to return value, as variable which I have mentioned is output parameter to the stored procedure and assigned through it. So is there any other way?